# How to set a windows form's AcceptButton to None at run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003

To set a form's AcceptButton at runtime, I'm doing this:

```
this.AcceptButton = this.btnButtonName;
```

But can anyone tell me how to clear the form's AcceptButton, something like:

```
this.AcceptButton = None;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.AcceptButton = null;
```

Comment: emm...yes - that worked.  Thank you.  ...can't believe I didn't try that myself!!.

Comment: If I had been in a bad mood, I might have suggested you comment out the line "this.AcceptButton = this.btnButtonName;", then look to see what the value was; then set it to that value at runtime. But I thought better of it. ;-)